# How to remove an object from array with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object

How can I remove an object from the attachment array?

So when I uploaded multiple images, I was able to upload images correctly but when it comes to remove an image, I got an error.

```
export default function App() {

  const attachments = [
    { id: 1, src: "asdadsa1" },
    { id: 2, src: "asdadsa2" },
    { id: 3, src: "asdadsa3" }
  ];

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    CARD_DEFAULTS,
    () => cardDocdument
  );

  function reducer(state, { type, value }) {
    switch (type) {
      case "setAttachments":
        return update(state, {
          attachments: { $set: [...state.attachments, value] }
        });
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
  }

  const updateAttachments = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      if (value === attachments) return;
      dispatch({ type: "setAttachmentsState", value });
    },
    [attachments]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child updateAttachments={updateAttachments} attachments={attachments} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React from "react";

const Child = ({ updateAttachments, attachments }) => {

  const saveAttachment = (files) => {
    const {length: filesLength} = files;
    for (let i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
      .
      .
      .
        const newAttachmentObj = addAttachment(fileObj);
        updateAttachments(newAttachmentObj);
      } 
    }
  };

  const handleDelete = (attachment) => {
    const newAttachObj = attachments.find(attachment => attachment.uuid !== attachment.uuid);
    updateAttachments(newAttachObj);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>upload images link</p>
      <button onClick={() => saveAttachment(files)}>Save images</button>
      {
        attachments.map((attachment) => (
          <div key={attachment.id}>
          <img src={attachment.src} />
          <p onClick={() => {handleDelete(attachment)}}>remove image</p>
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

So take a look at the code for saving images...

When users upload multiple images, there is a for loop, the `updateAttachments` gets called and pass image attachment object to set it to an array (`attachments: { $set: [...state.attachments, value] }`)

But when I remove an image, how can I remove an object that is clicked and set a new array without that object?

#### Attempts

```
  const handleDelete = (attachment) => {
    const newAttachObj = attachments.filter(
          ({uuid}) => uuid !== attachment.uuid,
        );
    
        const {length: attachmentsLength} = newValues;
        for (let i = 0; i < attachmentsLength; i++) {
          const attachObj = newValues[i];
          updateAttachments(attachObj);
        }
  }
```

This put the objected without one I clicked to the attachments array but added new objects after the objects already existing...

So when I removed third object (`{ id: 3, src: "asdadsa3" }`), this is what I see in the attachment array.
Btw `id` is generated randomly so see `src` are duplicated.

```
[
    { id: 1, src: "asdadsa1" },
    { id: 2, src: "asdadsa2" },
    { id: 3, src: "asdadsa1" },
    { id: 4, src: "asdadsa2" },
]
```

Comment: `attachments.find`? you mean `attachment.filter`?

Comment: @Qori I tried both way and neither of them didn't work